# htaccess редирект на симлинк

Tags: .htaccess, сервер, apache2, редирект

Привет. Помогите настроить htaccess
на сервере nginx+apache2
есть каталог проекта **/var/www/site.com**
в этом каталоге лежит htaccess 
здесь же есть симлинк webroot ведущий на каталог **/var/www/lands**
в котором подкаталоги лендингов **asd**, **zxc**, **qwe**
нужно чтобы на запросе **site.com/asd** показывался ленд из **webroot/asd**

пробую сделать так

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/license(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tender(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webroot/$1 [R=301,L]
```

а так же пробовал

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^tender$ webroot/tender$1
```

ни в какую не хотит арбайтен. 
Куда смотреть?

mod_rewrite работает

Answer (score 2):

Так работать и не будет, htaccess симлинков не видит, ему этот webroot ни о чем не говорит, он его просто явно подставляет.
У меня была похожая проблема: [.htaccess, внутренний редирект с поддомена на основной домен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560003/htaccess-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD) сказали, что можно ограничиться одним симлинком.