# .htaccess, внутренний редирект с поддомена на основной домен

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Доброго времени суток, уже второй день бьюсь над проблемой. Есть два сайта http://admin.example.ru и http://example.ru, на хостинге они расположены вот так: `/home/p111111/www/admin.example.ru/` и `/home/p111111/www/example.ru/`. Нужно настроить через .htaccess внутренний редирект так, что бы все файлы http://admin.example.ru брались с http://example.ru/admin, но внимание, без перезагрузки и изменения url.
Для упрощения, я пока пробую сделать редирект для одного файла, но этот код не работает.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/p111111/www/example.ru/
RewriteRule test.php admin/test.php
```

По началу думал, что это приколы хостинга, пробовал сделать локально на апаче, постоянно выдает ошибку  403 (Forbidden).

Answer (score 1):

Так у Вас и не должно работать. `RewriteBase` - url, который добавляется к результату обработки правилами, а не физический путь на сервере. Вам надо использовать симлинки на каталоги или делать редирект.

Comment: Редирект это не то что нужно, а как использовать симлинки?

Comment: Вот я создал через консоль symboliclink на директорию /home/p111111/www/example.ru/admin, как мне указать в htaccess чтоб файлы брались через нее?

Comment: Вам .htaccess и не нужен, если Вы симлинк сделали. Это то же самое, что и физически файлы переместить в нужный каталог.

Comment: Ну оно не работает, может я что-то не так делаю, приведу упрощенный пример. Допустим у меня есть файл `/home/p111111/www/example.ru/admin/test.php` и я делаю на него симлинк этой командой: `ln -s www/example.ru/admin/test.php www/admin.example.ru/test`, тоесть при вводе http://admin.example.ru/test у меня должен открыться тот файл `test.php`?

Comment: Если Вы сделаете симлинк на каталог, например: `ln -s /home/p111111/www/example.ru/admin /home/p111111/www/admin.example.ru` и перейдете по адресу http://admin.example.ru/test.php, то выполнится скрипт /home/p111111/www/example.ru/admin/test.php, конечно если такой файл существует.

Comment: Не хочет работать, все равно открывает скрипты из admin.example.ru